# Error "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to shift my time series data, but I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

This is my code:

```
def create_dataset(datasets):
    #series = dataset
    temps = DataFrame(datasets.values)
    dataframes = concat(
        [temps, temps.shift(-1), temps.shift(-2), temps.shift(-3)], axis=1)
    lala = numpy.array(dataframes)
    return lala

    # Load
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv('zahlenreihe.csv', index_col=False,
    engine='python', header=None)
    dataset = dataframe.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

    # Split
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.70)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

    # Create
    trainX = create_dataset(train)
```

I think the following line is wrong:

```
temps = DataFrame(datasets.values)
```

My *zahlenreihe.csv* file (*number sequence*) just has integers ordered like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
n
```

How should I handle it?

Comment: What are you expecting `datasets.values` to be?

Comment: i am expecting this is as a row?

Comment: A pandas Dataframe or Dataset (column of a frame) has a .`values` attribute (probably a property).  The result in is `numpy` array.  But don't try to apply that twice.  An array does not have a `values` attribute.  Check the `type` of `datasets` or whatever object your error is complaining about.

Comment: Hmm, cant follow you. so i cant use a array to shift like the way i want to? datasets is a array yes

Comment: If it is already an array, you don't to add `values`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj !! That works, another little question: How can i remove all numpy rows which has naN elements?

Answer (score 27):

The solution:

The given dataset was already an array, so I didn’t need to call *.value*.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the following line:

`df = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)`

It returns a [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array (see the documentation), which does not have a drop function. You would have to convert it into a *pd.DataFrame* first!

`new_df = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)`